# query inside like operator

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

Can I use query inside the `like` operator.

I used the query below, but it returns error.

```
select * 
from customers
where cust_name like '%'||select name from members||'%'
```

Comment: Do you want to filter names from members? In that case, use a subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work :

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
 customers    c
WHERE 1=1
AND EXISTS
 (SELECT 1
  FROM members   m
  WHERE 1=1
  AND c.cust_name LIKE '%'||m.name||'%'
 )
```

Comment: The `WHERE 1=1` is useless

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  It's habit - I always put that in as the first where condition in case I need to start commenting out lines - don't want to keep moving 'WHERE'

Answer (score 1):

In `PLSQL` if you want to run a Query then you need to decalre a variable to hold the result of the query. So you can do it as :

```
DECLARE
   var   customers%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   SELECT c.*
     INTO var
     FROM customers c
          INNER JOIN members m ON c.cust_name LIKE '%' || m.name || '%';
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define the name part of members in subselect (works with only 1 row):

```
select * 
from customers
where cust_name like (select '%'||name||'%' from members);
```

Same can be done with JOIN (works with multiple rows):

```
select C.* 
from customers C 
INNER JOIN MEMBERS M ON (C.CUST_NAME LIKE '%'||M.NAME||'%');
```

Comment: I used the second one since I have more than 1 row to return from the sub query. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it is sufficient to enclose the subquery in parentheses

like as
cust_name like '%'||**(select name from members)**||'%'

but this only works when the table "members" has only one record